# Multiple Splash Screen with some Action

Tags: iphone, ios, splash-screen

Here's The probem.
I have an iPhone app that needs to have 2 splash screens. 
the first splashscreen will show for 1 or 2 second before it fading out and changing to the second splash screen and in the second splash screen it has [x]close button in the top right corner which similiar to windows close button.
and it has an action to close the second splash screen and go to the main window.

i already try to make it with variety of ways, but i'm not even close to the goal.
and maybe it's because i'm totally new in iphone apps development.

so guys, i really need your help..

Comment: Just a thought - how about no splash screens. Let your users actually use your app as quickly as possible. What you are trying to do is bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your request correctly, you can accomplish this by triggering a segue from your app delegate. Say, for example, that you want to do the following after app launch:

- Show View A for 2 seconds
- Fade to View B
- Have user tap [x] close button to reveal View C

You can something similar to the following if you are using Storyboards:

Configure an initial view controller `MYAViewController`. Add `MYBViewController`. Add `MYCViewController`.

Then set an outgoing segue from `MYAViewController` to `MYBViewController`. Select this segue and from the Attributes inspector, give it an Identifier of `AToB`, set its style to `Modal`, set its transition to `Cross Dissolve` and ensure that `Animates` is selected.

Add another segue from `MYBViewController` to `MYCViewController`. Select this segue and configure however you want to, but give it has an identifier of `BToC`.

Then from your app delegate, trigger the segues programmatically.

**In MYAppDelegate:**

```
...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self performSelector:@selector(showViewB) 
               withObject:nil 
               afterDelay:2.0]; // seconds
}

- (void)showViewB {
    [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AToB" 
        sender:self.window.rootViewController];
}

...
```

Note that all view controller names and segue identifiers are contrived. Obviously, you would want to name these items in a way that is meaningful to your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't develop my apps using storyboard